# Intersecting a minkowski difference from the origin in a direction, how do i find the face im intersecting?

Tags: algorithm, math, vector

Basically i have a set of vertices on the hull of a minkowski difference of two polyhedra. I want to find the distance from the origin to the hull in some arbitrary predetermined direction. Heres a quick 2D sketch:

[image]

So the issue is finding what triangular face/plane the ray is going to intersect. Once i have that plane i simply do a line/plane intersection test. My issue is finding the correct face/plane. Any ideas? Is there some set of dot product/cross product/triple product tests i can do to determine it? Or is it more complicated then that?

If your wondering what this is for im using a GJK algorithm to determine whether two objects are intersecting (which i've got working). If there is a collision i would like to find the penetration depth in a particular direction (which will be the direction of motion of the object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project the polyhedron in the direction of the ray, and your problem reduces to 2D, and finding which triangle encloses the origin. To test a single triangle, consider whether a given directed line segment (AB) is going clockwise or counterclockwise with respect to the origin. This is easy to determine with a simple cross-product test: it's counterclockwise iff **A** x (**B**-**A**) > 0.

If all three sides of a triangle have the same sense (clockwise or counterclockwise) then the triangle encloses the origin and that's the face you want.

**EDIT:**
Since your polyhedron is a hull it is convex, And since it is convex you can search the surface in an efficient way. You can traverse the edges in a very simple "walk uphill/downhill" way to find the two vertices farthest along the the ray in either direction. Then after you project the poyhedron you can start from these two points and do a similar climb toward the origin. This will be **O(sqrt(n))**.

Comment: Thanks for the response I appreciate it! Is there any method you know of that may be a little more efficient? That's a lot of square roots

Comment: *Eh?* I see only one square root, and that's to normalize the vector representing the ray-- where do you see them? This solution is O(n). There's a way to get to O(sqrt(n)), but it's hard to explain without diagrams...

Comment: ahh i mixed up the vectors in my head, great, thank you for the help!